# How do I sync calendars from my PC to my Samsung Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: sync, calendar, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have synced my PC and all calendar entries I have done on my phone appear on the calender on my PC, but not the other way around. I need to be able to add events etc. to my PC and have them appear on my phone.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What calendar are you using? Can you please provide the specific name of the app/program, and include it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Calendar on your PC and your phone. This will also gives you access to your calendar from any device with internet connection simply by logging into your Google account.